# Fazer deploy de um projeto em ReactJS usando NodeJS pode ocultar alguma lógica da aplicação?

Tags: node.js, react

Suponhamos que estou criando uma aplicação em ReactJS que faz uma série de solicitações para uma API externa usando `Axios`.

No meu caso, imagine que eu tenho um componente que chama um arquivo de serviço (`src/services/component.service.ts`) que por sua vez executa uma solicitação através do método POST para um endpoint enviando uma `secret key`.

Considerando que essa `secret key` é confidencial (e que eu não deveria lidar com isso no front-end), existe alguma maneira de mantê-la oculta durante a implantação da minha aplicação?

Por exemplo, eu sei que a partir do momento em que executo um `npm run build`, e gero os arquivos estáticos do meu projeto para disponibilizá-lo desta forma.

Um usuário mal-intencionado poderia pesquisar as solicitações para abrir os arquivos internos, até chegar ao ponto onde encontra a lógica da solicitação e a `secret key`.

Mas supondo que eu faça o deploy meu projeto usando NodeJS (sem gerar arquivos estáticos), a lógica existente em `component.service.ts` ficará visível para o usuário? O que consequentemente deixaria a chave secreta exposta?

Ou agora, por se tratar de uma aplicação meio front-end, meio back-end, essa informação estaria segura?

Recentemente fiz algumas pesquisas na internet, e encontrei esta resposta:

> Ao fazer deploy do seu aplicativo ReactJS usando Node.js sem gerar arquivos
> estáticos, a lógica em seu arquivo component.service.ts não ficará
> visível para os usuários da mesma forma que ficaria se você
> fizesse o deploy usando arquivos estáticos. Isso ocorre porque o código
> TypeScript/JavaScript é executado no lado do servidor e apenas os
> dados necessários são enviados para o lado do cliente (navegador).

Está correto? Nesse caso, não haveria nenhum problema em deixar a `secret key` dentro do `component.service.ts` ? (Isso é, se eu fizer deploy usando NodeJS é claro)

Comment: De qualquer forma a sua `secret key` ficará exposta para todo, pois a pessoa pode ir na guia `network` inspecionando no browser, essa feature está aberta em todos os navegadores atuais, sendo assim a pessoa consegue acessar as requisições inclusive conectando dispositivos mobiles a rede, sem contar com softwares que ficam "vigiando a rede" e por ai vai, ou seja, a sua `secret key` pode não aparecer de forma legível para qualquer pessoa no bundle da aplicação, mas estará disponível para qualquer pessoa que acessar.

Comment: O ideal nessas situações seria algum método de autenticação mais seguro junto para fazer um handshake entre front e backend.

Answer (score -4):

Você pode optar por usar Next.js ou alguma outra biblioteca ou alternativa que forneça renderização no lado do servidor. Assim, o componente que estiver no lado do servidor será responsável por realizar a requisição, e, consequentemente, a sua chave secreta não será exposta no navegador do cliente.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components